# Modifying Poll Template to have big buttons for voting

Tags: polls

I am re-skinning the poll module for an iPad/tablets.

How can I make the poll module vote page have large buttons/images instead of radio buttons.

The template has `<?php print $choice; ?>`

and thats it :(

Comment: I think this is a matter of css and nothing to do with php

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was overriding this theme function:

```
function media_preprocess_poll_vote(&$vars)
{
    $node = menu_get_object();
    $list = array();

    $vars['choice'] = '';
    $vars['vote'] = '';

    foreach ($node->choice as $i => $choice) 
    {
        $vars['choice'].= '
        <div class="poll-choice-wrapper">
            <input type="button" data-choice="'.$i.'" id="choice-'.$i.'" name="choice-'.$i.'" value="'.$choice['chtext'].'" class="poll-choice" />
        </div>';
    }

    $vars['choice'].='<input type="hidden" name="choice" id="choice" value="-1" />';
}
```

Then adding a little js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery(".poll-choice").click(function()
    {
        jQuery("#choice").val(jQuery(this).data('choice'));
        jQuery("#poll-view-voting").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory I think you could either use css https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909486/css-replacing-checkbox-image

Or how about hook_form_alter ,

Maybe something like

```
$form['actions']['input']['Checkbox' = 'image_button';
```